# Texture not drawn using OpenGL ES 2.0 and Android NDK

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I want to display an image as texture on a quad with OpenGL ES 2.0 using the Android NDK.

I have the following simple vertex and fragment shader:

```
#define DISP_SHADER_V_SRC "\
attribute vec4 aPos;\
attribute vec2 aTexCoord;\
varying vec2 vTexCoord;\
void main() {\
    gl_Position = aPos;\
    vTexCoord = aTexCoord;\
 }"

#define DISP_SHADER_F_SRC "\
precision mediump float;\n\
varying vec2 vTexCoord;\n\
uniform sampler2D sTexture;\n\
void main() {\n\
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTexCoord);\n\
}"
```

At first, a native "create" method is called when the GLSurfaceView is created. It sets the clear color, builds the shader and gets me a texture id using `glGenTextures`. A "resize" method sets the current view size. Another method sets the texture data like this:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

I don't believe that there's something wrong there. The important thing should be the "draw" method. After glClear, glViewport and glUseProgram I do the following:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(shAPos);
glVertexAttribPointer(shAPos, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, quadVertices);

glVertexAttribPointer(shATexCoord, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, quadTexCoordsStd);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shATexCoord);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
// now glDisableVertex...
```

I can confirm that the shader basically works, since `gl_FragColor=vec4(1.0);` results in a white screen. It just does not work when I load a texture. I tried out setting the pixel data to "all white" using `memset` just to confirm that the issue is not related with my image data, but still the screen stays black. What am I missing?

Comment: Since you're able to draw with a modified shader, it sounds like the sampler is just finding zeroes in the texture image.  Can you confirm that you're calling `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId)` before the `glTexImage2D` call?  Is the texture using power-of-two sizes?

Comment: I can confirm that. I'm calling  `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);`, then I set `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` and generate mipmaps. I also checked that `vTexCoord` has valid values by setting `gl_FragColor = vec4(vTexCoord.s, vTexCoord.t, 1.0, 1.0)`. It all does what it should, besides drawing the damn texture :(

Comment: Wow, this took some time... Well I'm not *completely* sure what the problem was, but I solved it like this: I noticed that drawing the texture worked when I called the texture loading function via JNI directly inside `onSurfaceCreated`. However, I wanted that the texture changes when I touch the view. I guessed it had something to do with the calling thread. So I moved the code to call the texture loading function from an `OnClickListener` directly to the class that implements the `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`. Now it works. Tricky thing though, since no errors were thrown :(

Comment: Sounds like you moved it to a different thread (UI thread vs. GLSurfaceView render thread).  Do you have the same EGL context current in both threads simultaneously?

Comment: I do not see any lines of code where you set the value of the uniform: `sTexture` to **0**.

Answer (score 1):

IsaacKleiner's own comment was correct, I have met with the same problem, I develop a android app with OpenGL ES 2.0 in C++, using NDK. The function to load texture was in the C++ part originally. For some reason, that did not work. Only after **I move the load texture code to java part** , did it work as normal. **I load the texture in the java part, bind it as normal, and I pass the texture ID to the C++ JNI code**. I do not know why there is such a problem. I can provide with [a link](http://blog.csdn.net/mnorst/article/details/40510361), in which there is an example that use OpenGL ES 1.0 and NDK to show a cube. Although it is in Chinese, the code can explain itself. please pay attention to how the texture is generated and how the texture id is passed between Java and C++.

Comment: Yes, to make this clear again: The root of the problem is that you cannot use OpenGL functions from two different threads. No matter if they are in the Java or in the C++ JNI part of your application, you should always call the OpenGL functions from the same thread (the very thread that created the EGL context). In my situation, I was calling a GL function from the UI Thread (as @fadden explained), which did not work. After moving it to the GLSurfaceView rendering thread it works.

Comment: Sorry but this answer is wrong, you definitely can load the texture on the C++ side. As Isaac discovered, OpenGL calls need to be called on a opengl thread (which completely another matter).